# EF Core many to many unique key relation problem in sales cart

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I want to create shopping cart model.

So I have created 3 tables: Cart, Items, CartItems

```
public class Cart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<CartItems> CartItems{ get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<CartItems> CartItems{ get; set; }
}

public class CartItems
{
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    public Cart Cart { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CartItems>().HasKey(x => new { x.CartId, x.ItemId });
}
```

Like in every shopping cart it is possible to have multiple same items in 1 cart, or have the same items in 2 or more carts.

But I cannot enter two same items into cart, because of unique key, so something went wrong.. could someone guide mw how this should be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new "ID" in CartItems table and set this ID as primary key. And re-update your dbcontext and model.